# Android Notification Timeout Listener

Tags: android, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

I did implement a notification feature in android using the Notification.Builder in Android OREO+. I need to cancel the notification after a certain time frame, if the user has not clicked on the notification. which i completed using the setTimeOutAfter method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTimeoutAfter(long).

Now, i need to send a message to server that the notification wasn't clicked/timeout has occured. How can i implement this? Is there any notificationTimeout Listener?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing like a timeout listener but you can use a delete intent for your purpose. You'll need a `Broadcast Receiver` in order to do something (like calling your server) when the notification gets dismissed.

In code:

```kotlin
class NotificationDismissedReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            // call your server here
        }
    }

    private fun getNotificationWithDeleteIntent() : Notification{
        val deleteIntent = Intent(context, NotificationDismissedReceiver::class.java)
        deleteIntent.action = "notification_cancelled"
        val onDismissPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, deleteIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setContentTitle(textTitle)
            .setContentText(textContent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setTimeoutAfter(TIMEOUT)
            .setDeleteIntent(onDismissPendingIntent)
        
        return builder.build()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola. It worked like a charm. You made my day :)

Comment: My pleasure , please mark the answer as accepted if you can